# Regex for finding the query from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a string with few values appended i wanted to find just the last part of the query.

**here is the code i have tried:**

```
var parseRawQuery = function (rawQuery) {
    var query = rawQuery.split(/([^']+)' /g);
    return query[2] || rawQuery;
};
```

what is a better alternative without using splitting by single quotes.

**Input: String(raw Query):**

```
INSERT NOCOMPRESS OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3://dev.abc.com/taz' select * from azb
```

**Output:**

```
select * from azb
```

**more Input:**

```
INSERT NOCOMPRESS OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3://a.abc.com/taz' CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.new_prop_table (`Col0` STRING)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION 's3://0.abc.com/asdf/' TBLPROPERTIES ('table_desc'='hello world');
```

**Output for above string:**

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.new_prop_table (`Col0` STRING)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION 's3://0.abc.com/asdf/' TBLPROPERTIES ('table_desc'='hello world');
```

Comment: Can you just put an example of the full string and part of the string?

Comment: So, what you want is "select * from azb" ? Also, can you put more examples of strings where you would get it from? Need some samples for proper regexing.

Comment: Can't really understand the meaning of your "more input". It doesn't have "select" things.

Comment: @blackmiaool i want the 3rd part of the string

in the above case i would need as output:

```CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.new_prop_table (`Col0` STRING)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION 's3://0.abc.com/asdf/' TBLPROPERTIES ('table_desc'='hello world');```

Comment: @TabraizAli ok, better update the question to let others understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish this using the following *regex* ...

```
'\w+:\/\/[\w.\/]+'\s(.*?$)
```

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bx53zv/1)**

**JavaScript**

```js
var str = "INSERT NOCOMPRESS OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3://a.abc.com/taz' CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.new_prop_table (`Col0` STRING)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION 's3://0.abc.com/asdf/' TBLPROPERTIES ('table_desc'='hello world');";
var query = str.match(/'\w+:\/\/[\w.\/]+'\s(.*?$)/)[1];
console.log(query);
```

Comment: there can be a single quote in the query

Comment: doesn't work for the second input i have added.

"INSERT NOCOMPRESS OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3://a.abc.com/taz' CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.new_prop_table (`Col0` STRING)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION 's3://0.abc.com/asdf/' TBLPROPERTIES ('table_desc'='hello world');"

Comment: @TabraizAli what would be the output for that?

Comment: just the query:

output:


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.new_prop_table (`Col0` STRING)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION 's3://0.abc.com/asdf/' TBLPROPERTIES ('table_desc'='hello world');

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's gonna have the same structure each time and there won't be any other single quotes, why not this:

```
var query = rawQuery.split("'");
return query[2].trim();
```

Then you always have only the part you want, no regex needed.

Comment: there can be a single quote in the query.

Comment: something like `indexOf("'")` and `lastIndexOf("'")`, I suppose? but if it has two queries it wouldn't work. But then you could split them in half if they have two queries.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know where does the middle part in your string come from. Maybe u can do something like this:

```js
var a="INSERT NOCOMPRESS OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3://a.abc.com/taz' CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.new_prop_table (`Col0` STRING)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION 's3://0.abc.com/asdf/' TBLPROPERTIES ('table_desc'='hello world');";
console.log(a.match(/'\w+:\/\/[\S]+?'([\s\S]+)$/)[1]);
```